# Four Gates - ארבעה שערים

Tags: calendar, rosh-hashanah-new-year, tishrei, molad

The [Tur OH 428](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.428.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) describes a system for finding the year's calendar based only on (a) the molad of this year's Tishrei, and (b) knowing which of last year, this year, and next year are regular or leap years. The system takes into account all of the ד' דחיות, automatically. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar#The_four_gates) it has been known since the time of the Gaonim. Wikipedia has a handy chart to illistrate it. Just take the time of the molad, find the right column, and you are pointing to the correct calendar.

Question: You can figure out each of the cells in the chart by hand if you understand the [ד' דחיות](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar#Rosh_Hashanah_postponement_rules), one by one. But has anyone seen a good graphical illustration of how the various cells in the chart work - an easy way to visualize it?

Answer (score 3):

Anyhow, I made one בע"ה, at https://michoelr.github.io/Keviyus/FourGates/FourGates.htm. I would love to hear comments and suggestions - web design is not my core skill at all.
A few points about using it:
a) You can set the molad for This ר"ה by hand, either by entering the values at the bottom or pulling the green pointer. The other molads for last year, next year, the year after that, all follow.
b) You can click on one of the year types, like מפ"פ, and the arrows will move to that column. The pointers on the left also adjust, so that the molads continue to be correctly linked to This ר"ה though the length of the years just changed.
c) In combination, the molad of "This ר"ה" and the year type column give you the green and red arrows that point to the correct calendar for the year, which is marked on the right.
d) If you click on one of the molad triplets in the Molad Tishrei column, it will set the molad in This ר"ה to that value (and maybe move the year type if needed). A tooltip also appears over each of the triplets, explaining why that molad changes the calendar and where you should look to see it (I've now added a little animation to make the right place to look easier to find). Also, the tooltip text appears below the charts in the Stories section. It always corresponds to a pointer reaching exactly ?d 18h 0ch on *one* of the calendars, because that's when calendars change.
Updated: For this option it also shows you colored vertical bars to the left of the rulers, which show when Rosh Hashana was *going* to be, and where it ended up.
e) You can now also enter in the *year* on the top right, and it will pick the correct column and set the correct molad for you, picking that year's calendar instantly.
Update: I made a brief PowerPoint on how to use this, here https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1nneOHFxS-16TQ-d_xXt9hXLoD--qTQNz/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=108360675515039678488&rtpof=true&sd=true I'd suggest downloading it rather than opening it in your browser, unless you have a pretty smart browser.

Comment: Very nice. Might be worth clarifying somewhere that the inputs follow Jewish time. So 2d 18h 0ch means noon on Monday. Otherwise, if people try to input actual times from a calendar they might get confused. E.g. this year's Molad Tishrei is often quoted as falling on Friday 5:49AM, rather than 6d 11h 882ch.

Comment: @JoelK Yeah. I'm a little leery of trying to give a whole primer on the Jewish calendar, and I don't know if anyone will appreciate this page if they aren't already familiar with it... But you may be right on this detail.

Comment: @JoelK Added some paragraphs of explanation. tl;dr :)

Comment: @JoelK Did anyone but me think that the "four gates" were the four types of year in the 19-year cycle? Very natural thing to think from that chart, but Wikipedia says otherwise. I was actually going to correct them, but I think it's right.

Comment: Yes - I thought the same as you. That's funny. How do you know that Wikipedia is correct?

Comment: @JoelK There's a number of teshuvos Gaonim about the R' Saadya Gaon-Aharon ben Meir controversy. Several of them explain their respective versions of the Four Gates. I believe it's clear from them (see for instance AbM's first letter, 15:9) that the Gates were the days of the week that RH falls, and the system gave the range of times of the molad for each one. Please correct me if you have a source that says otherwise.

Comment: I have a pdf of a recent book by Prof. Sacha Stern in London on the topic ("The Jewish Calendar Controversy..."), this letter is quoted in full. I don't have a better reference. But that was certainly not the point of disagreement with the sages of Bavel.

Comment: Another example: p. 159 he quotes the Sefer Hamoadim (attributed to R' Saadya Gaon), "the traditions of the 1st Gate are 491, 408, and 204; the traditions of the 2nd Gate are 695 and 204; the traditions of the 3rd Gate are six hours and 204; and the traditions of the 4th Gate are 491, 204 and 589..." Those correspond on my chart to the chalakim for Shabbos, Thursday, Tuesday, and Monday.